# Jmeter : How to use while loop to check value in array?

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to include below action in my Jmeter script.

I have a page which loads list of item ids once it is available in system. Once it is available I will perform some actions like exporting them. 
Here is the steps:

1. Added item and it has `id =3925`
2. Make `GET` request and extract `K_srcID`

`k_srcId=["3924","3923","3922","3921","3920","3919","3918","3914","3917","3915","3916","3913","3912","3911","3908","3909"]`

2. Now Loop and send `GET` request until first item in the  `K_srcID_1 == id`

How do I put this condition in While loop in Jmeter?

Comment: please try this `${__javaScript("${K_srcID}"=="3925")}`

Comment: Thanks Naveen. I was able to solve it. Added a json extractor to get the id value and looped it until ID is visible. If it is not available , send default value.

Answer (score 1):

If you really getting this JSON array and not able to process it furthen you can use the next While Controller condition

```
${__groovy(new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get("K_srcID"))[0] != "your ID",)}
```

Make sure to replace `your ID` with the actual ID you need to wait.

References:

- [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)
- [Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Groovy is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks Dimitri. I am not familiar with groovy , these links are really helpful.